# Когда долистываю до последнего элемента recyclerview в первый элемент заносятся его значения

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Всем привет!
Очень нужна ваша помощь (:
Когда программа запускается, то всё работает как надо, 1-й элемент показывается правильно

[image: Понедельник правильный вариант(1-й элемент)]

Но после того как дохожу до последнего элемента, который выглядит следующим образом:
[image: Последний элемент]

А потом пролистываю обратно к первому элементу, то значения у него меняются на те, которые были у последнего! Совершенно не понимаю почему.

[image: 1-й элемент после возвращения]

Мой `onBindViewHolder()` выглядит следующим образом:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ScheduleViewHolder holder, int position) {

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    holder.textViewWeekDay.setText("Понеділок");
                    if (mondayWeek.size() > 0) {
                        fillFields(mondayWeek, holder);
                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    holder.textViewWeekDay.setText("Вівторок");
                    if (tuesdayWeek.size() > 0) {
                        fillFields(tuesdayWeek, holder);
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    holder.textViewWeekDay.setText("Середа");
                    if (wednesdayWeek.size() > 0) {
                        fillFields(wednesdayWeek, holder);
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    holder.textViewWeekDay.setText("Четвер");
                    if (thursdayWeek.size() > 0) {
                        fillFields(thursdayWeek, holder);
                    }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    holder.textViewWeekDay.setText("Пятниця");
                    if (fridayWeek.size() > 0) {
                        fillFields(fridayWeek, holder);
                    }
                    break;
                case 5:
                    holder.textViewWeekDay.setText("Субота");
                    if (saturdayWeek.size() > 0) {
                        fillFields(saturdayWeek, holder);
                    }
                    break;
            }

    }
```

А метод `fillFields()` выглядит так:

```
private void fillFields (List<Lesson> lessons, ScheduleViewHolder holder) {
        ArrayList<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
        integers.add(1);
        integers.add(2);
        integers.add(3);
        integers.add(4);
        integers.add(5);

        for (Lesson lesson1: lessons) {
                integers.remove(Integer.valueOf(lesson1.getLessonNumber()));
                switch (Integer.parseInt(lesson1.getLessonNumber())) {
                    case 1:
                        holder.textView1LessonName.setText(lesson1.getLessonFullName());
                        holder.textView1TeacherName.setText(lesson1.getTeacherName());
                        holder.textView1Auditory.setText(lesson1.getLessonRoom());
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        holder.textView2LessonName.setText(lesson1.getLessonFullName());
                        holder.textView2TeacherName.setText(lesson1.getTeacherName());
                        holder.textView2Auditory.setText(lesson1.getLessonRoom());
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        holder.textView3LessonName.setText(lesson1.getLessonFullName());
                        holder.textView3TeacherName.setText(lesson1.getTeacherName());
                        holder.textView3Auditory.setText(lesson1.getLessonRoom());
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        holder.textView4LessonName.setText(lesson1.getLessonFullName());
                        holder.textView4TeacherName.setText(lesson1.getTeacherName());
                        holder.textView4Auditory.setText(lesson1.getLessonRoom());
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        holder.textView5LessonName.setText(lesson1.getLessonFullName());
                        holder.textView5TeacherName.setText(lesson1.getTeacherName());
                        holder.textView5Auditory.setText(lesson1.getLessonRoom());
                        break;
                }
        }


        for (int i : integers) {
            switch (i) {
                case 1:
                    holder.textView1LessonName.setText("");
                    holder.textView1TeacherName.setText("");
                    holder.textView1Auditory.setText("");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    holder.textView2LessonName.setText("");
                    holder.textView2TeacherName.setText("");
                    holder.textView2Auditory.setText("");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    holder.textView3LessonName.setText("");
                    holder.textView3TeacherName.setText("");
                    holder.textView3Auditory.setText("");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    holder.textView4LessonName.setText("");
                    holder.textView4TeacherName.setText("");
                    holder.textView4Auditory.setText("");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    holder.textView5LessonName.setText("");
                    holder.textView5TeacherName.setText("");
                    holder.textView5Auditory.setText("");
                    break;
            }
        }
        integers.clear();
        lessons.clear();

    }
```

Я буду благодарен за любую помощь и любые советы.
Заранее огромное спасибо :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RecyclerView во имя оптимизации для отображения разметки одиновых по типу ячеек берёт уже отрисованные ячейки из своего пула ячеек, куда попадают ячейки отрисованные, но уже не отображающиеся (скрытые в процессе прокрутки).

Именно вышеопианное и приводит к наблюдаемому вами результату. Чтобы это исправить - надо при заполнении ячейки информацией в onBindViewHolder устанавливать значения для всех вьюх в ячейке, не надеясь, что они изначально будут иметь значения по умолчанию.